# Laravel 5: OR operator in middleware groups

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I would like to have some routes which only be available for `auth:user` **OR** `auth:admin` middlewares.

I tried following code :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user', 'auth:admin']], function () {
   //many routes here
});
```

But seems like these routes are available for `auth:user` **AND** `auth:admin` at the same time!!!

I don't want **AND**. I need **OR**.

Any helps would be appreciated

---

**Update 1**

I decided to create new guard `userOradmin` in `/config/auth.php` file.

As you can see I have created new guard called `userOradmin` which points to provider `usersOrAdmins` (plural names) :

```
'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins'
        ],

        'userOradmin' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'usersOradmins'
        ]
    ]
```

And the provider is :

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class
        ],

        'usersOradmins' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => [App\Admin::class, App\User::class] // <-- Is that right?
        ]
```

The problem is here. Should I assign that two classes to `model` like that?!

Comment: What's the difference between OR and AND in this case?

Comment: @JilsonThomas Huge difference. In that case you must be logged as admin AND logged as user at the same time!!

Comment: only thing I can think of is to split it into to two separate groups

Comment: @DavidNguyen There are many routes. I don't want to copy these routes twice :(

Comment: i'm assuming you made your own middleware for these maybe have a look at some pre-made packages: https://github.com/romanbican/roles

Comment: @DavidNguyen, does romanbican/role package support AND/OR operators in middleware?
Zizaco/entrust package support it => It is possible to use pipe symbol as OR operator: 'middleware' => ['role:admin|root']

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a new middleware for this, `auth:userOrAdmin`.  Middlewares do not interact with each other, so neither of those middlewares know that the other exists.  They just get a request, check it, and send it down the line, so every middleware is inherently `AND`.

Comment: Please see my first post UPDATED

Comment: No need to make a new middleware. You can add support for multiple guards to the regular `Authenticate` middleware. See my answer. [I actually got that into Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3685).

Answer (score 2):

Swap out the `Authenticate` middleware with this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if ($this->check($guards)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is logged in to any of the given guards.
     *
     * @param  array  $guards
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function check(array $guards)
    {
        if (empty($guards)) {
            return Auth::check();
        }

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                Auth::shouldUse($guard);

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your routes:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user,admin']], function () {
   //many routes here
});
```